# Increment enum or set enum value by index

Tags: dart

I have an enum type:

```
enum Day {sunday, monday, tuesday...}
```

and a variable:

```
Day day = Day.sunday;
```

I would like to be able to increment the day. something like this:

```
day++; // this would be wonderful
day = Day.getByIndex(day.index + 1); // something like this can also work
```

But I couldn't find anything like this. Is the only option to use a switch on all days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b7f95e358b6945aad90db39bc3b375f6)

```
enum Day {sunday, monday, tuesday}
void main() {
    var day = Day.sunday;
  print(day);
  print(Day.values[day.index + 1]);
}
```

Dart enums are known to not be very powerful. I guess they'll get some overhaul eventually.